# Migrating from comercial mail provider to my own solution - fetch old mailadress

Tags: debian, email

Config: Debian 8, cyrus-IMAP, postfix

I am migrating from my long time commercial mail service provider to my own solution. I use cyrus and postfix. So far all works fine.

Now: What is the best way to fetch the mails from mail old provider and forward it to my own IMAP server. I want to do this on the server and not on my mail client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the provider won't configure a forward, take a look at FetchMail (http://www.fetchmail.info/) to do this for you.

Comment: No, they do not provide a forward. It's not their business model ;-)

Comment: Worked, thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [imapsync](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync) to grab the emails from your old provider.